# WebDAV Date Range query

Tags: c#, email, webdav, exchange-server-2003

Im trying to access and extract message from Exchange Server 2003. I need to get them by dates but im having problem with it.

Here's the code `lsQuery = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
                            + "<D:searchrequest xmlns:D = \"DAV:\" xmlns:m=\"urn:schemas:httpmail:\">"
                            + "<D:sql>SELECT \"urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment\", \"DAV:displayname\", "
                            + "\"urn:schemas:httpmail:from\", \"urn:schemas:httpmail:subject\", "
                            + "\"urn:schemas:httpmail:htmldescription\" FROM \"" + lsRootUri
                            + "\" WHERE \"DAV:ishidden\" = false "
                            + "AND \"DAV:isfolder\" = false " 
                            + "AND \"urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment\" = true "
                            + "AND \"urn:schemas:httpmail:read\" = false "
                            + "AND \"urn:schemas:httpmail:date \" \"&gt;=\" CAST(\"2009/11/17\" as 'dateTime') "
                            + "AND \"urn:schemas:httpmail:date \" \"&lt;=\" CAST(\"2009/11/19\" as 'dateTime') "
                            + "</D:sql></D:searchrequest>";`

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa123600%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx